# Which features of Pandas DataFrame could be used to model GPS Tracklog data (read from GPX file)

Tags: gps, pandas

It's been months now since I started to use Pandas DataFrame to deserialize GPS data and perform some data processing and analyses.

Although I am very impressed with Pandas robustness, flexibility and power, I'm a bit lost about which features, and in which way, I should use to properly model the data, both for clarity, simplicity and computational speed.

Basically, each DataFrame is primarily indexed by a `datetime` object, having at least one column for a latitude-longitude tuple, and one column for elevation.

The first thing I do is to calculate a new column with the geodesic distance between coordinate pairs (first one being 0.0), using a function that takes two coordinate pairs as arguments, and from that new column I can calculate the cumulative distance along the track, which I use as a [Linear Referencing System](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_linear_referencing)

The questions I need to address would be:

1. Is there a way in which I can use, in the same dataframe, two different monotonically increasing columns (cumulative distance and timestamp), choosing whatever is more convenient in each given context at runtime, and use these indexes to auto-align newly inserted rows?
2. In the specific case of applying a `diff` function that could be vectorized (applied like an array operation instead of an iterative pairwise loop), is there a way to do that idiomatically in pandas? Should I create a "coordinate" class which support the diff (`__sub__`) operation so I could use `dataframe.latlng.diff` directly?

I'm not sure these questions are well formulated, but that is due, at least a bit, by the overwhelming number of possibilities, and a somewhat fragmented documentation (yet).

Also, any tip about using Pandas for GPS data (tracklogs) or Geospatial data in general is very much welcome.

Thanks for any help!